# C# Global mutex for MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, multithreading

In MVC if I want to lock a method so that it will never run more than once at a time (despite multiple users using the application), I can just use a static object:

```
private static Object lock= new Object();
```

But in my case I want to create a lock with a name, so the application will only lock for those users trying to use the same name.

Normally in C# I would use a Mutex(name) for this, but is there an appropriate equivalent in server world? (it needs to be global for all users)

Edit:

This is a client application, rather than a public site - so there would only ever be max say, 20 users accessing the application at a time.

Comment: It won't work if you are going to use more than one web server or more than one application pool worker process.

Comment: Sounds like a classic x/y problem.  You should [edit] to include details of why you want to do this.

Comment: Run-once can't be implemented with locks - what happens if a request for a *different* tries to call the same method? Or the application pool restarts?  Run-once per user almost begs for a flag on a user-specific table. Besides, locking on a web server is begging for a crash.

Comment: Also, a *locked* method means the *client* will never get an answer until the request times out. And the client may retry, resulting in more timeouts

Comment: 20 users retrying an operation will still block the web site. Remember, a lock means that once a user calls the method he can never make any call to it until the server restarts. Even 1 user would be blocked this way. Why don't you store a flag in a table? What is the *X* problem that you are trying to solve with mutexes?

Comment: A flag in a table may well be a good approach if needed. I'm just trying to understand why it's more suitable: "a lock means that once a user calls the method he can never make any call to it until the server restarts". Surely the user can call it again once the lock is released? (once the work has been done). If I have a named locked, trying to figure out why this is different to a flag on a table? Thanks.

Comment: I think the long and short is that you need to use a shared persistent datastore. The problem with statics in the context of a web application is that the App Pool can really restart any time. It usually recycles on a schedule. It can crash. The server/IIS could restart, etc. Any time that happens the state of the static variables are reset. Additionally, if you use web workers, each worker has its own distinct App Pool instance, and therefore it's own distinct statics. By storing in something like SQL Server, you have a common data store to pull from.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense - thanks for clarifying all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do not want to block anything on server side, what you want is *to not execute anything* on server side once condition is met. It can be handled in number of ways: Error page redirection, Notification to the client about critical condition met...etc

In other words, for selected users, handle that special condition, but 
**do not block anything**.